# looping through a database to show information within divs

Tags: html, asp.net, css

I am just starting out in ASP.NET with previous experience in C++ and was wondering if you can help me out/point me in the right direction here.

I know how to link an Access database to visual studio's web forms however when showing the data I have found the tables to be very ugly so wanted to populate classes with the data.

In my "product details" database are; product name, price, description, rating, cost etc.

Using this information from the database I understand that my code should attempt to connect to the database server then attempt to access the specified database schema.

By giving the database any table name I hoped to return an array of all rows with all data inside it, possibly within a function called selectingData? As it loops through each row, it stores the data as an associative array which is then saved as a new array element.

I could then apply some styling...

```
<div style="float:left; width:50%;">  ...logic of code... </div>

<div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

Comment: read tutorials! if problem, then ask here if not asked yet!

Comment: I see a lot of similar questions relating to PHP however that is not what I have been instructed to learn and a lot of tutorials are "click this", "type this" etc. Was hoping for a gentle push in the right direction, however thankyou for your fast reply!

Answer (score -1):

You should use Sql Server Express 2008 or 2012, might as well use 2012. Download and install, make sure to include Sql Server Management Studio with your installation package install. You can choose server only but you want the Sql Server Management Studio tool included in your install as well.

Sql Server Management Studio will easily import your Access database and make a Sql Database of it. Right click your localhost server after you install in Sql Server Management Studio and click Import and follow wizard options, there is a source type setting for Microsoft Access database.

From here you want to use Entity Framework 5 or 6 via Visual Studio 2012 or 2013. Visual Studio 2012 or 2013 Web Express are always free and the best IDE ever. You can generate a model of your imported access database. Just create a new ASP.NET Website (go with MVC) and then right click the project and select Add -> Add New Menu Item -> EF5.x or EF 6.x DbContext Generator. This will give you the functionality you need via Linq to query tables, get result sets, manipulate those result sets and bind them to your display HTML.

You might as well do things the right way since you are getting into ASP.NET. This path is a treat and easy to learn but you will have a day or two of a learning curve ahead of you.

Comment: When using SQL Server Express on my computer, is localhost\sqlexpress the root folder of my own server name? When I first started the query builder in VS the dialogue box lets me select both the origional Access database tables and the new VS ones - I have included the VS ones in the query but does this mean I have two connection strings still active? Also, when pressing the execute query button there was a distinct lag, what may cause this - is this due to data or my machine?

Comment: Shouldn't be any lag. localhost\sqlexpress is the sql server instance running on your computer. It is a Windows service that is always listening.

I VS means Visual Studio and you originally used VS to connect to the access database than yes you still have an active connection string to the Access database file on your computer which you can delete. VS is emulating a sql server like connection to the Access database file. If the Access data file is massive and I mean massive then it could be data otherwise the lag is most likely your machine. Perhaps reboot if you haven't in a while.

Comment: Thank-you for your reply! I had been running the computer for a little over 15 hours by this time so that **MIGHT** have been the cause! I never realised how much of this work has the potential to be drag and drop based. When you say "manipulate those result sets and bind them to your display HTML." Do you mean my initial looping class idea? I can't quite explain how repulsed I am by ListView in the toolbar!

Comment: Well I don't do too much drag and drop myself but using Entity Framework to build a model of your database does have a Diagram visualizer to see all your tables and their relationships. What I mean by "manipulate those result sets and bind them to your display HTML." Is getting results using your Entity Framework Context that was created to write a query in Linq, get the records and display them on an .aspx page or cshtml view.

Comment: This is brilliant!! Thank-you so much :) I am eager to learn I just had little idea where to start...!

Comment: Sure np, and you can mark my question correct if you want ;)